# Html isnt showing up in kivy

Tags: python, kivy

I have a simple kivy app where i want to add some HTMl using tkhtmlview

```
this is the code:
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label 
import requests 
from kivy.clock import Clock
from tkhtmlview import HTMLLabel
 

class EthereumPriceApp(App):

    def update_price(self, lbl):
        url = requests.get("https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/simple/price?ids=ethereum&vs_currencies=usd").json()
        price = url['ethereum']['usd']
        lbl.text = "Ethereum Price\n " +" " + str(price) + " USD"
        HTMLLabel(html='<a href="https://www.google.com">Hello world</a>').pack()
        
    def build(self):
            
        lbl = Label(font_size=72)
        self.update_price(lbl)
        Clock.schedule_interval(lambda _:self.update_price(lbl), 120) # updates every 1 second

        return lbl

if __name__ == '__main__':
    EthereumPriceApp().run()
```

When i run this i dont see my HTML anywhere, whats the issue?

Comment: I don't think you have any code that would display HTML - merely instantiating a HTMLLabel won't do anything. You'll need to write a tkinter app to display that, using whatever api tkinter has.

Comment: you right dude, i thought this also works in kivy